# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.put(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: spring, maven, apache-poi, jira, poi

делаю плагин для Jira, понадобилась библиотека poi для работы с excel. Добавил 2 зависимости:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

После добавления строчки `WorkBook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();` в сервлет и перехода по обрабатываемому им URL адресу бросает ошибки:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2021-05-24 16:51:46,794 http-nio-2990-exec-4 ERROR      
[o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/jira].[servlet-module-container-servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet [servlet-module-container-servlet] in context with path [/jira] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.put(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.<clinit>(SharedStringsTable.java:91)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
```

Как мне решить эту проблему? На обычном спринговом проекте всё работает даже с одной зависимостью `poi-ooxml`, а тут не хочет(

Comment: Удалось решить проблему?

Comment: @EugeneCuz не удалось